# ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F~/Documents/FacebookSDK' - react-native - ios

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I have been trying to deal with a lot of problems since I upgraded the react-native version of my app. 
One of those was this that came out of nowhere!

**ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F~/Documents/FacebookSDK'**

Followed by these (which caused extra confusion)

> ld: library not found for -lRCTWebSocket clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some googling and used some tips trying to solve it. Most of them did not work. So I decided I should share the solution that worked for me.

Quote from another SO discussion:

> if your error includes the -L flag, then delete the values in Library
>   Search Paths if your error includes the -F flag, then delete the
>   values in Framework Search Paths

I checked the **framework search path** values under **Build Settings** 
It was like this:

[image]

For both Release and Debug configurations.
I deleted the line for FacebookSDK (line 3) from both release and debug configurations, and did another `react-native run-ios`.
And it worked!

I hope this helps...